# Parse back json in php

Tags: php, json

I have written a function like

```
     public function abc()
     {  
         if()
         {
           ...
           ...
             $cursor = ....
         }
         else
         {
         $cursor = json_encode(json_decode ("{}"));
        }
        return $cursor;
     }
```

Now in another function

```
     public function def()
     {
        $cursor = abc():
        if($cursor !="{}")
        {
          ...
        }
     }
```

I am not able to check condition for empty json which I passed from abc function.
Please help !!!

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$cursor`? are you sure its not `[]`? Why are you encoding it into json in the first place, you would only need to encode once you spit it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `associative` flag when decoding the json data. This will return the data as a normal PHP array which you can then use the `empty()` on for your test.

```
<?php
$json = "{}";
if (empty(json_decode($json, true))) {
    echo "empty";
}
// empty
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to check emptiness of json, with casting and counting.

```
if (count((array)$cursor)){
 // your code goes here   
}
```